# How to draw a stroke outline using CGContext API?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, cgcontext

I have an icon image I would like to draw a 1px, colored 0.5 opacity line around, inside the image (similar to Stroke layer style with position:inside in Photoshop). So far I've tried this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(inCompositeSize, NO, inBaseImage.scale);
            context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        CGContextDrawImage(context, frame, image.CGImage);
        CGColorSpaceRef cs = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGContextSetStrokeColorSpace(context, cs);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(cs);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
//...
```

This seems to have no effect. I'm guessing this is because I'm working with an image and not a path. How can I produce an outline stroke effect on the image?

Clarification: I'm trying to draw an outline on the opaque icon area only. The icon background is 0 alpha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StrokePath` strokes a path, and you haven't plotted a path. That's why it strokes nothing.

You need to do either of two things:

1. Vectorize the raster image and stroke that path. Core Image's edge-detection filter will help, but even so, this is hard. There is no built-in API for this; you'll have to find a library that does it or do it yourself.
2. Fake it by drawing the image with a shadow. Note that shadows can be any color; it doesn't have to look like a shadow.

Comment: Right, I tried #2 but it doesn't draw inside the shape, obviously. But it may be the closest thing.

Comment: @Plenilune: The way to get the shadow inside/over the image is to make an inverse mask image from the image, clip to that mask, and then fill with any solid color with the shadow. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextClipToMask To make the mask, create a CGBitmapContext, draw the image into it, set the blend mode to Source In, fill with black, set the blend mode to Destination Atop, and fill with white.

Comment: Clarification: “any solid color” should be the background.